# Is there a zero-time, startup (no recompilation) switchable condition flag in Java?

Tags: java, performance, debugging, classloader, jit

I'm looking for a way to provide the fastest (I mean **zero-time** - compilation/classloading/JIT time resolved) possible **On/Off flag** for `if` condition. Of course this condition will be changed only once per application run - at startup.

I know that "compile-time constant if conditions" can be conditionaly compiled and whole condition can be removed from code. But what is the fastest (and possibly simple) alternative without need to recompile sources?

Can I move condition to separate `.jar` with single class & method with condition, where I produce two versions of that `.jar` and will swtich those versions in classpath on application startup? **Will JIT remove call to method** in separate `.jar` **if it discovers, that method is empty**?

Can I do it by providing two classes in classpath implementing "ClassWithMyCondition", where one of those class will have a real implementation and second will have just empty method and instantiate one of it by `Class.forName` and `.newInstance()`?Will JIT remove call to empty method from my primary very loop-nested method?

What can be simplest byte-code manipulation solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you give me a reason to downvote this? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: Why do you need to accomplish this?

Comment: Suppose I have a very heavy-debugging/logging logic (concrete a image representing algorithm results etc.) wich I want to be able turn on and off after shipping to end user.

Comment: Seems they don't know the answer :) +1.good question so far.

Comment: If that's the case, I would use @rolfl option and/or declare a constant which value is loaded from a configuration file. In both cases, you won't need to recompile the whole application. For example, JSF lets you achieve this through `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` context param, which values are `Development` and `Production` (there are others, but these two give you the idea).

Comment: why not just simply pass into the program a command line argument? I do this for a few programs, and just wrap the java program startup in a shell script with pipes in the correct cmd argument. The program runs and uses the input to determine the correct path.

Comment: You might be able to use Java's assertion capability for this. It would be ugly though. If the `assert` fails, an `AssertionError` is thrown, which you could catch and perform your extra logging, etc.

Comment: isn't `assert` only part of junit library? in any case, it's extremely bad practice to rely on an exception being thrown to do something... not only is performance greatly impacted (exception and stacktrace generation take time), but you should always strive to catch these as early as possible in code.

Comment: @erickson Sun/Oracle doesn't recommend handling any error at all, and any wrong assertion results in an assertion **error**.

Comment: @SnakeDoc you can enable assertions in your Java code since Java 4. Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html

Comment: @SnakeDoc No. `assert` is a Java language key word. It's not zero-cost, but because it utilizes a static final flag, it is easily optimized away.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Right. I specified that `AssertionError` is thrown, and opined that this approach is "ugly."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass custom values in the command line, and then check for that value once.  So in your code, have something like this:

```
final static boolean customProp = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(System.getProperty("customProp"));
```

Depending on your command line parameters, the `static final` value will change.  This will set the value to `true`:

```
java -DcustomProp="true" -jar app.jar
```

While this will set the value to `false`:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

This gives you the benefits of a `static final boolean`, but allows the value to be altered without recompiling.

---

**[Edit]**

As indicated in the comments, this approach does not allow for optimizations at compile time.  The value of the `static final boolean` is set on classload, and is unchanged from there.  "Normal" execution of the bytecode will likely need to evaluate every `if (customProp)`.  However, JIT happens at runtime, compiling bytecode down to native code.  At this point, since the bytecode has the runtime value, more aggressive optimizations like inlining or excluding code are possible.  Note that you cannot predict exactly if or when the JIT will kick in, though.

Comment: Will it make it `compile time constant` and exlude if from code when JITeed?

Comment: But this doesn't conform to the OPs requirements. The `if(customProp)` condition will be evaluated every time it's used.

Comment: @killer_PL `customProp` is a constant (`static final`), so yes, it should work.

Comment: JIT happens at runtime, so I would expect that any static final would be considered constant and allow for inline/exclude optimizations.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The condition is evaluated only once, when the class is loaded.

Comment: @killer_PL It will be optimized away at runtime by the JIT, but perhaps only after many executions; this behavior is implementation-specific. It *won't* be optimized away at compile time, because it's not a compile-time constant.

Comment: @EricGrunzke I agree, but this would be implementation specific to the JVM being used, and even the JIT used by the JVM could do it, there is no guarantee that it will, for whatever reason. I think that caveat should be mentioned in an answer talking about JIT or Java micro optimizations in general.

Comment: All good points. I edited the answer in an attempt to capture and summarize them.

Answer (score 11):

A standard way to do this sort of logic is to create an interface for the functionality you want, and then to create two (or more) implementations for that functionality. Only one of the implementations will be loaded in your runtime, and that implementation can make the assumptions it needs to in order to avoid the `if` condition entirely.

This has the advantage that each implementation is mutually exclusive, and things like the JIT compiler can ignore all the useless code for this particular run.

Comment: But this violates basic DRY and duplicates code. Do you mean that I can move inner-if logic to other implementation and JIT will remove call to empty method?

Comment: DRY ? No, think of things like java.util.List ... Instead of one class that has a conditional in every method to say `if (linked) { do linked list things } else { do array-list things }` you instead have two implementations of `List`, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, and you select the one you want, and there's no need for `if`.

Comment: I agree entirely, this should be done through polymorphism **not** `if` conditions. +1

Comment: A second comment, the actual implementations of `java.util.List` are typically based off java.util.AbstractList, and as a consequence, code reuse is maxemized....

Comment: I don't understand. Suppose that my business logic have 10 lines in method, and debugging/logging have 3. Now I have to write class with bussines logic - 10 lines, and with debug - 10+3 lines (10 lines duplicated). Or I am missing somethig. Did you mean somethind like `decorator` which add logging/debuging around methods? My business logic is very cross-cutted with debuging (nested loops, debugs in every loop, in several steps of most inner loop etc. I cannot so easly separate everythig without creating looot of method calls

Comment: I mean: just remebmber that I will NOT create two implementations like ArrayList and LinkedList - one implementation contains other

Comment: That can also lead to bloat and indirection. Say you have debugging code that asks the OS for info (reads files, etc) and then prints that out. Is your idea to have an interface `DebugInfo` with a method `debugFooMethodInSomeClass(int someLocal, String somethingElse, Foo someInstanceField)` with two implementations, a no-op and one that gets the info and logs it? And now we need a new method on that interface _every_ time you want to add debugging somewhere, and implement it in both the "real" implementation and the no-op? This is over-engineered relative to just using an if statement.

Comment: @yshavit I think the idea is to have something like `SLF4J`. You have a no-op implementation and an operative implementation. There is no need to couple the logging methods to the classes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The only works for some things. slf4j has fairly limited functionality from a programmer's perspective: print a message, optionally with a stack trace. And even then, it _still_ has `isDebugEnabled()` et al. because it recognizes that collecting debug information can be expensive, and polymorphism doesn't always solve everything.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution works here. Don't overcomplicate things for yourself.

Just put a `final static boolean` that *isn't* a compile-time constant (as defined in the JLS) somewhere and reference it wherever you want the "conditional" compilation. The JVM will evaluate it the first time it sees it, and by the time the code gets JIT'ed, the JVM will know that the value won't change and can then remove the check and, if the value is `false`, the block.

Some sources: Oracle has a wiki page on [performance techniques](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques) which says to use constants when possible (note that in this context, the compiler is the JVM/JIT, and therefore a `final` field counts as a constant even if it isn't a compile-time constant by JLS standards). That page links to an [index of performance tactics](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTacticIndex) the JIT takes, which mentions techniques such as constant folding and flow-sensitive rewrites, including dead code removal.

Comment: But I need to recompile code if I chagne boolean value - what I want to avoid. I mean - how I will provide switching to end-user witout need to recomplile .java to .class

Comment: Just make the boolean `final` but not a compile-time constant. `public static boolean propertiesIncludeHelloWorld = "world".equals(System.getProperty("hello"))` or whatever. It'll get evaluated at runtime, once, and then treated by the JVM/JIT as a constant for purposes of inlining and removing dead code.

Comment: Sounds good, upvote. Have you any documentation that condition will be removed totally, even if this is not a compile time constant? (JLS or sth)

Comment: @yshavit did you forget to include `final` in your comment code or was it intentional to use `public static boolean` without `final`?

Comment: You would need to be very careful here. When the code is compiled then compile time constants will be inlined. **All dependent code** will need to be recompiled if the constant is changed.

Comment: @yshavit: The simplest compile-time non-constant is `static final boolean b = Boolean.TRUE`. But using the property is way more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

you should load the value from a properties file so that you can avoid having to recompile each time it cahnges. Simply update the text file and on next program run, it uses the new value. Here's an example I wrote a long time ago:

https://github.com/SnakeDoc/JUtils/blob/master/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/Config.java

Answer (score 0):

The JIT recompiles the code every time you run it.  You are doing this already whether you know it or not.  This means if you have a field which the JIT believe is not changed (it doesn't even have to be final) it will be inlined and the check and code optimised away.

Trying to out smart the JIT is getting harder over time.